# Certain values in a array subdocument need to be unique

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas for an auction app I am building. One for the auction itself and it includes a subdocument array of bids.

Here is how my Auction schema looks like:

```
const auctionSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        isActive: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true
        },
        duration: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        bids: [Bid.schema]
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);
```

And this is my Bids schema:

```
const bidSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        bidder: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        amount: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            index: {
                unique: true,
                partialFilterExpression: { amount: { $type: "number" } }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);
```

My goal is that a certain bid amount can only exist once in that array. But the bidder value can be a duplicate.

Here is how I am writing into the auction document:

```
    var query = { 'tokenId': tokenId },
        update = { $push: { bids: bidBody } };

    Auction.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

But unfortunately I can create duplicates with no issue.

Comment: so the question is to allow duplicates only if duplicate has the max value from the existing ones? for example if  `1 3 5`  we cant add 1, but we can add 5? or we cant add any of the 1,3,5 ?  the bellow answer if you want all bidder to be unique,and never allow duplicate.

Comment: So basically if there is a bid with bidder "bob" and the amount is 10 there cannot be another bidder "susan" with the amount 10. This should be prohibited. But "bob" or "susan" can bid another time with a higher bid than 10.